# How to check fabricjs text is multi line?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm using fabric js. 
Today i struck with this question "**How to check fabricjs text is multi line?**". 
Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried?  See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

`fabricjs` text have a `_textLines` property. if text have a multi line this property add a each line as a array.So we can use this for check.

```js
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

$('#multi').click(function(){
 canvas.clear();
  var text = new fabric.Text('Hai this is\nmulti line\nHello World', {});
  canvas.add(text);
  $('#check').removeAttr('disabled')
})
$('#single').click(function(){
 canvas.clear();
  var text = new fabric.Text('Hai this is single line Hello World', {});
  canvas.add(text);
  $('#check').removeAttr('disabled')
})
$('#check').click(function(){
 console.log(canvas.getObjects()[0]._textLines.length)
  check = canvas.getObjects()[0]._textLines.length;
 if(check>1){
   alert("hey this is multi line text")
  }
  else if(check==1)
  {
   alert("hey this is single line")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
<button id="multi">add multi line text
</button>
<button id="single">add single line text
</button>
<button id="check" disabled="">check
</button>
```

Comment: @Mullainathan if this answer is helpful for you please check the acceptable answer tick mark.because this will help others also..:-)

Comment: be carefull that _textLines is a private property. It is initialized just after rendering. if you skip the canvas.add part, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would just check if the text can be splitted by newlines.

```
var myText = new fabric.Text('Hai this is single line Hello World', {});
var multiline = myText.text.split('\n').length > 1 ? true : false;
```

Comment: `split(/\n\r|\n|\r/)` covers all bases, Mac & Windows & Linux. See: https://danielmiessler.com/study/crlf/